# How to prevent layoutSubviews being called when transforming sublayers?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I have some `Layer1` attached to the root layer of my custom view as sublayer.

And then this funny thing happens that when I have changed the transform of `Layer1` inside `touchesMoved`, layoutSubviews is called.

I know there are all kinds of way to bypass this. But what's the logic behind it? Can it be prevented, instead of that I need find walk arounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be preventable.

My usual solution is to add another view to the hierarchy in between the parent and the child. The new view essentially works as a dummy container and does nothing on its `layoutSubviews`.